# Rendering HTML directly without using a template

Tags: python, django

What is the simplest way to return HTML without rendering a template?

Something like:

```
return HttpResponse('<html><p>Hello!</p></html>')
```

If I just do this as above, it will render it as a string instead of html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set content type to `text/html`:

```
return HttpResponse("<html><p>Hello!</p></html>", content_type="text/html")
```

It should be [default content type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__) unless you've set `DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` setting to something else.